# In Alloy Titanuim, How to close widget's parent window

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have a widget that contain a back button, when click that back button i want to close the window that having the widget (parent window).
here is my widget.xml :

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="topBar">
        <View id="leftItems">
            <ImageView id="backIcon" onClick="previousPage" />
            <ImageView id="logo" />
        </View>
        <View id="midItems">
            <Label id="pageTitle"></Label>
            <ImageView id="searchIcon" onClick="searchIcon" platform="ios" />
            <SearchBar id="searchBar" platform="ios" />
            <SearchView id="searchView" ns="Ti.UI.Android" platform="android" onBlur="pageTitleVisiability" onFocus="pageTitleVisiability" />
        </View>
        <View id="rightItems">
            <ImageView id="createIcon" onClick="createPost" />
        </View>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

and in widget.js :

```
function previousPage(argument) {
    // closing the window
}
```

i tried to send the custom property in the widget with the window name like this:

Alloy.createController('windowName').close();

but it says that the window is not opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create the controller in the widget and try to close it, you are creating a new instance of the window, not referencing the calling controller.  I would use messaging to perform the close.  Inside you previousPage function, add "$.trigger('closeParent');" to signal to close the window.  Then inside the calling window (where the widget is referenced) add something like "$..on('closeParent', );" and then close the window in the function.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: i tried to trigger the event on previousPage function and in the calling window $.on('closeParent', function() {alert('something');});  but no thing happened, any help

Comment: now it works when i put the "on" event in the widget id like so  " $widgetId.on('closeParent', function() {alert('something');}); " , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting callbacks should solve your problem.

your "widget.js" :

```
var previousPageCallback;

function previousPage() {
    if(previousPageCallback) previousPageCallback();
}

module.exports = {
    previousPageCallback : previousPageCallback
};
```

your "previousWindow.xml"

```
<Window>
    <Widget id="myWidget" src="<whateverYourWidgetNameIs>"/>
</Window>
```

your "previousWindow.js" (the window where you are using the widget)

```
$.myWidget.previousPageCallback = $.previousWindow.close();
```

Thanks n cheers

Comment: it return "Window is not open. Ignoring this close call"